# IO utilization percent of 4920.45% - iostat -x , What's wrong?

Tags: linux, io, iostat

I have seen wrong percent use of a disk IO some times on servers that have been a long time without reboot.

By any means this server has significant IO. Tonight it'll be rebooted and I'm sure tomorow we will have nice %use.
Uptime is 497 days.

```
root@xxxxxx:~# iostat -x 1
Linux 2.6.24-27-server (xxxxxx)         10/13/2011

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.55    0.00    0.30    7.54    0.00   91.60

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  **%util**

sda           17649.65   765.65 5478.46 5262.33 36185.00 48224.35     7.86    19.06    1.78   4.58 **4920.45**
```

The only thing is that nagios sees this as critical.

Any explanation will be wellcomed.

Thank you in advance.

---

Added later:

As you can see, the statistics are 0, and the % is going down quite slowly.

```
Linux 2.6.24-27-server (xxxxxxx)         10/13/2011

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.55    0.00    0.30    7.54    0.00   91.61

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util sda           13578.30  
590.03 4214.71 4048.69 27838.04 37110.10     7.86    14.67    1.78   4.58 3785.44

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util sda               0.00    
0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util sda               0.00    
0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util sda               0.00    
0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util sda               0.00    
0.00    0.00   10.00     0.00    80.00     8.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util sda               0.00    
0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util sda               0.00    
0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: Please append the output of `w` and `ps -eo pid,user,state,command | awk '$3 == /D/ { print $0 }'` at that time?

Comment: **Related Question**: [How the util of iostat is computed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458183/how-the-util-of-iostat-is-computed)

Answer (score 5):

The source code for `iostat` has a cut off of 100% on the calculation for `%util`. Either your version of `iostat` has some modification in this computation and it doesn't mean what it normally means or something *very* strange has happened.

Take a look at lines 381 and 382 in the [iostat.c source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#VV2vTPpLahE/trunk/Tools/iostat/iostat.c&q=iostat&sa=N&cd=6&ct=rc&l=2):

```
            if (busy > 100.0)
                    busy = 100.0;
```

If you look down at lines 386 and 394, you can see that `busy` is what is printed as `%util`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've added some more samples for iostat -x 1, maybe there is more light in them.

Comment: As I said, solved after a reboot. Thanks to every body